# Dynamic number of nested loops (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript

> I want to generate every possible combination of numbers, with *n* beeing the highest.

Eg:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

---

My current approach to this is pretty simple, just *n* for loops.
The problem with this is, that I don't know *n*.

```
n = 3;
for (a=0; a <= n; a++) {
    for (b=0; b <= n; b++) {
        for (c=0; c <= n; c++) {
            console.log(`${a} ${b} ${c}`);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I need a way of generating these loop dynamically.

*Any other approach for generating all possibilities is also welcome.*

Comment: Make it a function that takes `n` as a parameter? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a function for a cartesian product, an array of the wanted signs and the wanted length and return this result.

```js
function getCombinations(signs, length) {
    const cartesian = array => array
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));
    
    return cartesian(Array.from({ length }, _ => signs));
}

console.log(getCombinations([1, 2, 3], 5).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This could work. I'm gonna try to implement this in my application now, thank you for your quick response.